# Le pronom "on" à l'écrit formel : phrase impersonnelle avec "on" ou à la voix passive ?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-impersonnels

Je comprends très bien que l'on doit éviter de remplacer "nous" par "on" dans les situations formelles. Mais et quand à l'utilisation de "on" pour les phrases impersonnelles ?

Est-ce que le pronom impersonnel "on" ne doit pas être utilisé à l'écrit (contextes formels) même quand on formule des phrases impersonnelles, générales, etc ?

Quelques français m'ont dit qu'il faut le remplacer par la voix passive dans ce cas. Pourtant, même dans les textes formels, je vois que le pronom "on" est beaucoup utilisé.

Par exemple, dans un e-mail à une secrétaire, mon directeur de thèse (un français) a écrit :

> On a dit à Hilder lors de la journée d'accueil qu'il devrait acquérir des ECTS durant sa thèse.

Serait-il mieux d'écrire quelque chose comme "*Il a été dit à Hilder lors de la journée d'accueil qu'il devrait acquérir des ECTS durant sa thèse.*" ?

Un deuxième exemple: devrais-je écrire "*Les mathématiques sont beaucoup étudiées en France*" à la place de "*On étudie beaucoup les mathématiques en France*" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de raison d'écarter ***on*** des textes formels dans les cas cités, en particulier le deuxième où il a parfaitement à sa place.

Dans la première phrase, *on* est un peu ambigu car on ne sait pas s'il inclut ou non la personne qui s'exprime. La version avec *il a été dit* ne présente plus cette ambiguïté.

Voir [ce texte de l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/pauvre) qui défend *on* dans tous ses usages et contient les deux citations suivantes :

> On a souvent besoin d’un plus petit que soi. *Le Lion et le Rat*, La Fontaine
>
> À vaincre sans péril, on triomphe sans gloire. *Le Cid*, Corneille

Comment: Et pensez-vous que c'est possible d'écrire cette phrase de Corneille à la voix passive ? Car, en vraie, je ne vois même pas comment la transformer. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Ce serait quelque chose comme *Sans gloire est « triomphée » une victoire sans péril*, mais *triompher* ne s'emploie jamais à la voix passive.

Comment: D'accord. C'est pour cette raison alors que je ne trouvais pas un équivalent à la voie passive. Je suis désolé de vous poser autant de questions, mais voyez-vous une façon de remplacer le pronom "on" pour quelque chose d'autre dans cette même phrase ? C'est plutôt par curiosité, je comprends qu'elle est déjà bien écrite. Merci encore une fois.

Comment: *Vaincre sans péril, c'est triompher sans gloire*.

Comment: *Ceux qui vainquent sans péril, ils triomphent sans gloire.*